# Better way to get cross data before send to UDF in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, fuzzy-comparison

I want to use fuzzy UDF that I was created, compare each person list with all content data by send them to UDF. In order to do that I decide to use **CROSS** data before send to it.

Here is my sample person list,

```
101|PORAWAT
102|HADI
103|RIO
```

And my content which each data might contains more than one person and data can be similar(due to typo):

```
1001|case1|PORACWAT VS RIO CORP
1002|case2|PANIT
```

To send data to UDF, I decide to use CROSS data before call UDF, here is my code:

```
REGISTER hdfs:/user/hue/myudfs.jar;

-- LOAD
person_list = LOAD '/user/hue/data/person' USING PigStorage('|') as (p_id:chararray,p_name:chararray);
content_list =  LOAD '/user/hue/data/content' USING PigStorage('|') as (c_id:chararray,c_caseid:chararray,c_content:chararray);

-- CROSS
person_cross_content = CROSS person_list, content_list;

DESCRIBE person_cross_content;
person_cross_content : {person_list::p_id: chararray,person_list::p_name: chararray,content_list::c_id: chararray,content_list::c_caseid: chararray,content_list::c_content: chararray}
```

So, cross content will be:

```
101,PORAWAT,1001,case1,PORACWAT X RIO CORP
101,PORAWAT,1002,case2,PANIT
102,HADI,1001,case1,PORACWAT X RIO CORP
102,HADI,1002,case2,PANIT
103,RIO,1001,case1,PORACWAT X RIO CORP
103,RIO,1002,case2,PANIT
```

Then, check all person with all content with my Fuzzy UDF and get just only exact/similary match result, I will call like:

```
-- MyFuzzyMatching will return true when p_name occurred(exact/similar) in c_content
A = FOREACH person_cross_content GENERATE p_name, c_caseid, myudfs.MyFuzzyMatching(p_name,c_content) as (fuzzy_result:chararray);

-- Filter just only match result
FILTER A BY fuzzy_result == 'true';

-- Store the result ...
```

Thus, output to be like:

```
PORAWAT,case1,true
RIO,case1,true
```

When I execute this script command, it's take **very long time** to get the result when I use real data. Regarding to Pig reference, it's not recommend to use CROSS because of expensive operation but I have no idea how to achieve these.

Is there any better way to send all person with all content to UDF?

Answer (score 0):

If your data size if huge, CROSS might lead to performance problems ([think you know this already](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#cross)). One option is to project out the fields  (p_name,c_content) that you require for your UDF to separate relations and cross them. With lesser data, CROSS could be slightly faster. You can join them back after running your UDF.